# "material-table" how to reduce spaces between columns in react.js

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styling, material-table

I am using material-table in react.js from "@material-ui/core" and trying to reduce the large gap in b/w columns. here is the table...[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oXV7.png)

the data in the table, I'm fetching it from a dummy api. also I want to reduce the width of the whole table but that I could do with just normal css application into the div container.

[desired image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSkcu.png)

here is my code for that:-

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./paginationTable.css";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

// Import Material Icons
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import AddBox from "@material-ui/icons/AddBox";
import ArrowDownward from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward";
import Check from "@material-ui/icons/Check";
import ChevronLeft from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRight from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import Clear from "@material-ui/icons/Clear";
import DeleteOutline from "@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline";
import Edit from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import FilterList from "@material-ui/icons/FilterList";
import FirstPage from "@material-ui/icons/FirstPage";
import LastPage from "@material-ui/icons/LastPage";
import Remove from "@material-ui/icons/Remove";
import SaveAlt from "@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt";
import Search from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import ViewColumn from "@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn";
import { Link } from "@material-ui/core";

const tableIcons = {
  Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
  DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />
  )),
  Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
  FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
  LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
  NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
  PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />
  )),
  ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
  SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
  ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
  ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />),
};

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setData(res);
      });
  }, []);
  var len = data.length;
  // console.log(len);
  // Material Table Columns
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "ID",
      field: "id",
      editable: false,
      headerStyle: {
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "hwb(12deg 0% 0% / 86%)",
      },
    },
    {
      title: "Station Name",
      field: "address.street",
      headerStyle: {
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "hwb(12deg 0% 0% / 86%)",
      },
    },
    {
      title: "Location",
      field: "address.city",
      headerStyle: {
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "hwb(12deg 0% 0% / 86%)",
      },
    },
    {
      title: "Status",
      field: "availibilityStatus",
      headerStyle: {
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "hwb(12deg 0% 0% / 86%)",
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App_wrapper">
      <MaterialTable
        title=" "
        icons={tableIcons}
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        editable={{
          onRowAdd: (newRow) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              len++;
              const updatedRows = [...data, { id: len, ...newRow }];
              setTimeout(() => {
                setData(updatedRows);
                resolve();
              }, 20);
              console.log(newRow);
            }),
          onRowDelete: (selectedRow) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              const index = selectedRow.tableData.id;
              const updatedRows = [...data];
              updatedRows.splice(index, 1);
              setTimeout(() => {
                setData(updatedRows);
                console.log(selectedRow);
                resolve();
              }, 20);
            }),
          onRowUpdate: (updatedRow, oldRow) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              const index = oldRow.tableData.id;
              const updatedRows = [...data];
              updatedRows[index] = updatedRow;
              console.log("updated row", updatedRow);
              setTimeout(() => {
                setData(updatedRows);
                console.log(updatedRow);
                resolve();
              }, 20);
            }),
          onBulkUpdate: (selectedRows) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              const rows = Object.values(selectedRows);
              const updatedRows = [...data];
              let index;
              rows.map((emp) => {
                index = emp.oldData.tableData.id;
                updatedRows[index] = emp.newData;
              });
              setData(updatedRows);
              resolve();
            }),
        }}
        options={{
          actionsColumnIndex: -1,
          addRowPosition: "first",
          headerStyle: {
            color: "white",
            backgroundColor: "hwb(12deg 0% 0% / 86%)",
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

For that, I've tried "columnGap" and "width" properties but it's not working.